# String assignment in a list in a 'for' loop

Tags: python, string, list, loops, for-loop

I have a list `['1', '2', '3', '4']`
and I want to convert it to the following: `['1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0']`.
In the code below, why does the second attempt work and not the first?

```
>>> list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> for element in list:
...     element = element + '.0'
...
>>> print(list)
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> for element in range(len(list)):
...     list[element] = list[element] + '.0'
...
>>> print(list)
['1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0']
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as variable name.

Comment: how could have first attempt worked, you are modifying each `element` not  each `list element`

Comment: Woops, forgot about that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element` is the local variable and assigned only to the current element of list.

In the second case `list[element]` is assigned to list in which `element` points to the current index of list.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the list. You merely update the element variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [x + '.0' for x in old_list]
```

Comment: That's an answer, but not to the question asked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: regardless of not being an answer, thanks, that's really helpful

Comment: @Philio This is very much an answer, and not a comment. You downvote a bad answer, not delete it.

Comment: @Korem you said that it was not an answer to the question asked? Hence I flagged it from review as not answering the right question.

Comment: @Philio you reviewed this answer as being more fitting as a comment. This is not the case. There is no "unuseful answer" review, and for a reason.

Comment: Thanx guys for -1 :) play with it more :)